# Can't connect to local network using static IP - Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP server which has 2 NICs enp5s0f0 and enp5s0f1. I have both configured in /etc/network/interfaces since it's a server and has no graphical interface which could make problems if I do this. When I start the server I'm not able to find it on the network with nmap 10.0.0.0/24 -p and can't ping my gateway from the server. If I put the interfaces down and only enp5s0f1 up suddenly the ping is working. So I thought that the config or the network cable of interface 0 has some problems. I Checked the config file and switched LAN cables. I found no mistake in the config file. So my Question is what could be wrong with my Setup (network and software)

Note: networking worked fine till I started playing around with bridges so I don't think it's an Hardware issue. I removed all bridge config parts from the config file

The NIC names should be right - **dmesg | grep eth**

```
[   22.402049] igb 0000:05:00.0: added PHC on eth0
[   22.537417] igb 0000:05:00.0: eth0: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x4) xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.xx
[   22.606443] igb 0000:05:00.0: eth0: PBA No: Unknown
[   23.006031] igb 0000:05:00.1: added PHC on eth1
[   23.142435] igb 0000:05:00.1: eth1: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x4) xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.xx
[   23.211388] igb 0000:05:00.1: eth1: PBA No: Unknown
[   23.423252] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0f0: renamed from eth0
[   23.513177] igb 0000:05:00.1 enp5s0f1: renamed from eth1
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp5s0f0
iface enp5s0f0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.241
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.205
    dns-nameservers 10.0.0.205
auto enp5s0f1
iface enp5s0f1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.242
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.205
    dns-nameservers 10.0.0.205
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the first interface is working with DHCP even if the second one is on static

**EDIT2:** also using a bridge to KVM it is possible to connect over enp5s0f0 with a static bridge IP

Comment: You shouldn't have two gateway statements.

Comment: Why this? I tried without a gateway for the first interface, but no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Both are in the same subnet `10.0.0.0/24`, AFAIK, this is will not work.

  Change the second one to another subnet/network, example:

  ```
  source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto enp5s0f0
  iface enp5s0f0 inet static
      address 10.0.0.241
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 10.0.0.205
      dns-nameservers 10.0.0.205

  auto enp5s0f1
  iface enp5s0f1 inet static
      address 10.0.1.241
      netmask 255.255.255.0
  ```
- This question [multiple physical interfaces with IPs on the same subnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/415304/multiple-physical-interfaces-with-ips-on-the-same-subnet) has nice answer why this happening.

Comment: not tried this yet cause with a KVM bridge it is working for now. There is no solution to put both NICs in the same subnet except for bonding?

Comment: @Fritz, AFAIK, yes (even bonding it means you theoretically just used single interface for same subnet). Here is a nice question for someone tried to setup two interface on the same subnet, https://serverfault.com/questions/336021/two-network-interfaces-and-two-ip-addresses-on-the-same-subnet-in-linux .

Comment: @Fritz, This has a nice accepted answer about this topic, https://serverfault.com/questions/415304/multiple-physical-interfaces-with-ips-on-the-same-subnet

Comment: I accepted the answer ;) your link made it clear to me why this is happening. but bridging one interface should make no problems (even if there is only 1 interface in this bridge)?

Comment: @Ravan yep i'm there